# Get data from other files and post into daily report

Tags: excel, vba

I automated daily performance reports I send to my team. I would like to clean it up and optimize.

Through an application we store our data. We have data files dumping into a server we host. My VBA code pulls from this folder based on name of file, copies a cell and posts into my report.

There are two problems.

- Once it opens the Excel file it doesn't close it, leaving a lot of files open and unpleasing experience.
- Causes lag when the processes is occurring as its spamming between sheet to sheet.
  How can I make the process not show?

```vb
' Sheet 14 Import

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "S:\Root\Operations2\Reports\Trade Date Cash\scheduler\V14*.xls*"
    Range("L7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Daily Balances - Portfolio Size.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Testing").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
' Sheet 15 Import

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "S:\Root\Operations2\Reports\Trade Date Cash\scheduler\V15_*.xls*"
    Range("L7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Daily Balances - Portfolio Size.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Testing").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I have this code 30 times for every different name going from V13-V45 and posting into cell going down F.E from 14-15 pasting into B3->B4

Comment: You can close workbooks and set screenupdating to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your 30 need_to_be_opened csv workbooks are in one folder, which is:
S:\Root\Operations2\Reports\Trade Date Cash\scheduler\

and all the cell to be copied in the opened workbook is always cell L7,
and the L7 value of the first opened csv file will always be put in cell B3 with the name of the csv file in cell C3

Then you can loop to each file in that folder to only the csv files:

Something like this :

```
Sub test()
Dim p As String: Dim fn As Variant: Dim fso As Object: Dim oFill As Range

p = "S:\Root\Operations2\Reports\Trade Date Cash\scheduler\"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFill = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")

    For Each fn In fso.GetFolder(p).Files
        If fso.GetExtensionName(fn) = "csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=fn
        oFill.Value = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("L7").Value
        oFill.Offset(0, 1).Value = fn.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set oFill = oFill.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

The code will loop to each csv file which in the value of p variable (the path of the folder), open the file, get the value of cell L7 in the activesheet of the opened workbook then put that value to cell B3 for the first opened file and fill cell C3 with the name of this first opened file.

the second iteration, it will put the L7 value of the second opened file in cell B4 and the name of this second opened file in C4.

the third iteration, it will put the L7 of the third opened file in cell B5 and the name of this third opened file in C5.

And so on.

The thing which I don't understand is :

> **posting into cell going down F.E** from 14-15 pasting into B3->B4

....

> it gave me a "Compile Error: For Each control variable must be Variant
> or Object"

Sorry my mistake, please have a look to the revised test sub above.

Comment: Would this work if you had both PDF and CSV files within the folder? We would only want it to extract from the CSV file, I tried to test this code and it gave me a "Compile Error: For Each control variable must be Variant or Object". Lastly, how would I know which value was received from which file so if it extracted the value from v14 file I would like to know V14 = that value maybe in a new column next to the value rather than combined with the value. Thank you very much for your time and help!

As far as your question, It would overwrite yesterdays values, if that is an issue I can clear.

Comment: @edsaniti, please have a look to the edited sub in my answer. Please don't just copy the sub then run it without reading my explanation first ya.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate all the assistance! This is amazing, very well explained. If you wouldn't mind, is there a possible if statement to place in the event the value after filling from cell L2 is blank then look for value in K2?

Comment: What workbook of "if cell L2 is blank" ? If the opened workbook, I thought you want cell L7 value of the opened workbook ? Please CMIIW. Anyway, I assumed what you mean is cell L7. So, before put the value to the workbook with macro, you can have the code something like this `if ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("L7").Value = "" then oFill.Value = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value else oFill.Value = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("L7").Value` as the replacement for this line `oFill.Value = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("L7").Value`

Comment: You are 100% correct, I had wrote L2 as when changing between CSV and XLSX  the cell reference changed due to formatting. I appreciate all your help, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=false
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
            "S:\Root\Operations2\Reports\Trade Date Cash\scheduler\V14*.xls*"
Workbooks("Daily Balances - Portfolio Size.xlsm").Worksheets("Testing").Range("B3")=ActiveSheet.Range("L7").Value2
ActiveWorkbook.close SaveChanges:=False
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "S:\Root\Operations2\Reports\Trade Date Cash\scheduler\V15_*.xls*"
Workbooks("Daily Balances - Portfolio Size.xlsm").Worksheets("Testing").Range("B4")=ActiveSheet.Range("L7").Value2
ActiveWorkbook.close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating=true
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked very well, I appreciate it!